# How to optimise my batch script code

Tags: batch-file

Hi I want to optimise below batch script into single line code. I tried multiple ways but unable to do. Can you please help me here to optimise below code.

```
IF "%EnvName%"=="UT" (SET EnvName=UT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="UT1" (SET EnvName=UT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="UT2" (SET EnvName=UT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="ST" (SET EnvName=ST)
IF "%EnvName%"=="ST1" (SET EnvName=ST)
IF "%EnvName%"=="ST2" (SET EnvName=ST)
IF "%EnvName%"=="ST3" (SET EnvName=ST)
IF "%EnvName%"=="SIT" (SET EnvName=SIT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="SIT1" (SET EnvName=SIT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="SIT2" (SET EnvName=SIT) 
IF "%EnvName%"=="SIT3" (SET EnvName=SIT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="SIT4" (SET EnvName=SIT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="UAT" (SET EnvName=UAT) 
IF "%EnvName%"=="UAT1" (SET EnvName=UAT) 
IF "%EnvName%"=="UAT2" (SET EnvName=UAT) 
IF "%EnvName%"=="UAT3" (SET EnvName=UAT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="UAT4" (SET EnvName=UAT)
IF "%EnvName%"=="SND" (SET EnvName=SND) 
IF "%EnvName%"=="SND1" (SET EnvName=SND) 
IF "%EnvName%"=="SND2" (SET EnvName=SND) 
IF "%EnvName%"=="SND3" (SET EnvName=SND)
IF "%EnvName%"=="SND4" (SET EnvName=SND)
IF "%EnvName%"=="DEVL" (SET EnvName=DEVL)
IF "%EnvName%"=="DM" (SET EnvName=DM)
```

Comment: All you need to do is to remove the ending digit or are there any additional checks?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question here because it might suit better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The specifications are incomplete: what should be the result when `%EnvName%` does _not_ contain anyone of the listed values? Otherwise, lines like `IF "%EnvName%"=="DEVL" (SET EnvName=DEVL)` have no sense... See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696769/how-to-optimise-my-batch-script-code/41699900#41699900)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
REM EnvName gets set somewhere here
set "numbers=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"
for %%a in (%numbers%) do (
  if "%EnvName:~-1%"=="%%a" (
    set "EnvName=%EnvName:~0,-1%"
    goto :nextStep
  )
)
:nextStep
echo %EnvName%
```

Loops through all digits and checks whether the last character of your variable equals one of them. If so, it will remove that last digit and go to the next step which in my case is just echoing the variable.

Example with `%EnvName%=DLM3` -> `DLM`

*Note:* This will **only** remove the last character if it is a digit not any more!

Comment: @Sreenivas.konuganti Note that you can (and should) accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the question. This will not only help to keep the system clean, but also reward you!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the sets of valid names:
set "set[UT]=2, set[ST]=3, set[SIT]=4, set[UAT]=4, set[SND]=4, set[DEVL]=0, set[DM]=0" 

set "digits=123456789"


rem The Value:
set "EnvName=%1"


rem Separate parts
set "base=%EnvName:~0,-1%"
set "last=%EnvName:~-1%"

rem If last char is a digit
if "!digits:%last%=!" neq "%digits%" (

   rem Check the digit vs. max value
   if "%last%" leq "!set[%base%]!" set "EnvName=%base%"

) else (

   rem Check the value vs. defined sets
   if defined set[%EnvName%] set "EnvName=%EnvName%"

   rem Note that previous IF is meaningless, unless an ELSE is inserted here
   rem or a different variable is used for the result

)
```